# Spark metrics error: CsvReporter: Error writing to jvm.PS-MarkSweep.count

Tags: file-io, apache-spark, hdfs, metrics

I have configured Spark to run on two nodes with HDFS hosting the input files. I would like to dump all the stats file provided by metrics.properties to HDFS or each node's local directory.

Here is my configuration for the stats location of metrics.properties:

`*.sink.csv.directory=hdfs://ip:port/user/spark_stats/`

I have also tried to make a temporary local directory in every node and configure metrics.properties as follows:

```
*.sink.csv.directory=/tmp/spark_stats/
```

Both approaches give errors as follows:

```
16/03/02 15:41:49 WARN CsvReporter: Error writing to jvm.PS-MarkSweep.count
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
        at com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter.report(CsvReporter.java:241)
        at com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter.reportGauge(CsvReporter.java:234)
        at com.codahale.metrics.CsvReporter.report(CsvReporter.java:150)
        at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:162)
        at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/03/02 15:41:49 WARN CsvReporter: Error writing to jvm.PS-MarkSweep.count
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
....
```

My application still runs and finishes fine. But the spark log file shows there are errors writing the stats file. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Follow up: after carefully looking at the error messages, all the IO errors are caused by writing into master jvm information. If I specify to dump just the worker, driver, and executors' jvm information, there is no error.

A fix can be putting this line in the metric.properties file:
    `executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource`

Answer (score 0):

This Error is coming because the CSVRepoter is actually designed to append the new metrics in the same file. As HDFS as limitation of appending the same file hence CSV Repoter is writing into a localfile.

This error is occuring because given path is missing in local file system .